# How to change version of enqueue scripts and styles in WordPress using a plugin

Tags: wordpress

I want to apply version number from theme options to all those styles and scripts where version is set to true. Default version number is 1 but I want to manage it from theme options using a plugin. If version is set to true then grab all those scripts and styles and add the new version number to them.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know if there's a more clean way to achieve this but this piece of code does exactly what you asked for:

```
function stack_wp_script_version_change(){
    global $wp_scripts;
    
    /** @var _WP_Dependency $regScript */
    foreach ( $wp_scripts->registered as &$regScript ) {
        $regScript->ver = "my_custom_ver";
    }

}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','stack_wp_script_version_change',999);
```

I've tested it and the version actually change